# Microsft Owin Facebook authentication is not working in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, owin

I am working in Asp.Net MVC appplication. I am using the default visual studio project template. Google authentication is working fine but facebook doesn't. I specified a valid appId and appSecred generated on my facebook developer portal and the app is available to the public.

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
       appId: "111111111111",
       appSecret: "aaaaaaaaa");
```

After the user tries to login with facebook, the system redirects to [https://localhost:44301/Account/Login#*=*](https://localhost:44301/Account/Login#_=_)

It is not entering to /Account/ExternalLoginCallback, so I assume the login failed.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to NuGet Package Manager and run this command `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` and try doing the log in.

Comment: Kindly let me know if the above steps works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

3.0 uses obsolete APIs, update to 3.1. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38