# How to enable Facebook Login using the ASP.NET MVC project template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, owin

Forgive me for posting this duplicate question. This question has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523602/microsft-owin-facebook-authentication-is-not-working-in-mvc-application), but the accepted answer does not seem to apply anymore.

Just like the other user, I am using the default project template for ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2017. Also, just like the other user, I can get the Google authentication to work using Google+ API. But the Facebook authentication is not working properly.

```
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
    consumerKey: "fehdfkjhflkjdh",
    consumerSecret: "feifhlerkhgjrkd");

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
    appId: "49876254986",
    appSecret: "6k54hjl36jk");

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "547625983-iuho435hu34kh54k3h5kjhl52k4.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ClientSecret = "dfd8sa7f6ds878"
});
```

*(The secrets and IDs are all faked!)*

The suggestion to install the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` package was not needed on my end, because I already had it installed and it was already at version 3.0.1. I went on and updated it to the latest version available, which is currently 4.0.0 as per the screenshot below.

[image]

I have been following the official guide on how to set this up, as found on the Microsoft Docs (which does seem to be dated). Note that I was able to use the ASP.NET Core MVC template (as per Microsoft Docs) and enable Google, Facebook and Twitter authentication. So I should know how it's done. It's something with the ASP.NET MVC template specifically, and/or OWIN that's not working correctly.

Comment: What's the error message? How do you know it's "not working properly"?

Comment: "Not working correctly" is not a problem statement. What specifically happens, when, and does it spit out any useful errors? One possibility is that Facebook may need to call back to your server and if it is on localhost Facebook can't reach it (I don't know this for certain about Facebook, but that is how some handshakes work in general).